# Could not verify JWT: JWSError JWSInvalidSignature

Tags: next.js, jwt, hasura

[image: hasura configs]

[image: jwt]

I have configured hasura config as given in the image and generated token using jwt as shown in the image

but in hasura i am getting this error : "Could not verify JWT: JWSError JWSInvalidSignature"

EDIT :
after changing the token now the error solved but now there is no query available:
[image: no_query_available]

Comment: Is the signature part of the token (the last segment highlighted in blue on jwt.io) identical? It can happen when you input the secret after you pasted the token on the left side, that the signature gets recalculated and then it shows signature verified. So please check the signature part and make sure the secret is the correct one.

Comment: sorry to say, i didn't get you.

Comment: I ask if the signature that you see on jwt.io is identical to the signature of the token in the first image. Many people use jwt.io in the wrong way and then the signature changes (getting recalculated)

Comment: edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue involved mismatch access token secret key resulting in the error

> JWT: JWSError JWSInvalidSignature.

Ensure you added the Hasura environmental variable on Hasura side:

```
JWT_SECRET: { "type": "HS256", "key": "your access token secret key"}
```

The same "your access token secret key" should be used in your app to encrypt your access token before sending it to the Hasura API.

Let me know if that works.